# How to display dialog box inside textFieldSearch after selecting an item in search dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-alertdialog

I'm searching from textFieldSearch, after selecting an item from searchDropdown I want a popUp

What I tried ->
In textFieldSearch getSelected property I tried calling AlertDialog, But it's not displaying.
What I'm expecting ->
After selecting an item from searchDropDown I want a popUp

Comment: Can you provide some code which you've tried before

Comment: In TextFieldSearch widget, there is a dropdown, there I'm calling the below code                                                                                Future<List> fetchData()async{
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    List list = [];
    for(int i=0; i<invoiceList.length; i++){
      if(invoiceList[i]['status'] == "") {
        list.add(InvoiceData.fromJson(invoiceList[i]));
      }
    }
    return list;
  }, Here I'm getting only non-Invoiced data. For now it is okay. But if I get invoiced data in dropdown after selecting it I should get a popUp

Comment: umm you can edit your question to add the code and then formatting it to code format by selecting it and pressing ctrl+k (cmd+k for macos)